# I have problems with my app alignment when i launch it

Tags: java, android, android-layout

When I launch my app on my device every thing get ordered as right to left but when I launch it on the emulator it stays the way it is. I know that the problem is that my device's main language is Hebrew (and Hebrew is a language where you write from right to left ) and the emulator's language is English.

picture 1

[image: this is how it shows on my device]

picture 2

[image: this is how it is intended to be]

I want it to be the same in all languages.

Thanks in advance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.mahmood.morsecode.TextToMorse">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="344dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="BackSpace" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Space" />
</LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: And where is your code?

Comment: There is no code yet, the problem is in the layout.

Comment: I did not have this problem in the past, it showed just when i got Android Studio 3.0 ( the latest version i think)

Comment: "There is no code yet, the problem is in the layout".... The layout is created with code

Comment: I edited the post , sorry for any inconvenience, i thought the code doesn't matter because yesterday it wasn't like this, and I'm using same app and code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `AndroidManifest.xml`. By default, Android Studio will add this attribute to the `<application>` tag:

```
android:supportsRtl="true"
```

Change that to `false`, and layout direction based on language will be ignored.

Documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#supportsrtl

Comment: Well, that was easy.
Thank alot

Answer (score 0):

Go through your layout and change `start` to `left`, and `end` to `right` e.g. where you have `layout_marginStart` change to `layout_marginLeft`.

Doing so should change your layout to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.mahmood.morsecode.TextToMorse">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="344dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="BackSpace" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Space" />
</LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: either these variables don't accept (left,right..) or I'm not entering them properly. im entering them in the right attributes

Comment: Try this. Open `Find and Replace` on your XML in Android Studio (Ctrl+R I think), find `Start` and replace all with `Left`, then replace all `End` with `Right`. That's what I mean.

Comment: Or just use the version I posted.

Comment: i used both methods and still the same :(